# Solr Search Query for word must occur after specific position

Tags: solr

I want to write Solr query for something as below :

apple w/5 pear - apple must occur within 5 words of pear

How i can achieve the same ? Is their any regex for same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by enclosing the terms in quotations and using a tilde to indicate proximity:

`q="apple pear"~5`

If just the quotations are present, that is the same as ~0, that is, they should be next to each other.

Comment: if i have something like this in a document "John is going to school" and i say q= "John school"~3 or "John school"~2 or "John school"~1  or "John school"~12, it returns same result ??

Comment: There will be a match for "John school"~3 and "John school"~4 but not for "John school"~2, or "John school"~1 because there are 3 words between John and school.

Comment: How i can search apple must not occur within 5 words of pear ?

Comment: @user662285 `!"apple pear"~5`. But if you need apple and pear to be present but not within 5 words of each other, you need to add that to the search `q=(apple AND pear) AND !"apple pear"~5`